# Parallel random number generation with Akka Futures

Tags: scala, random, akka, future

I'm writing a CPU intensive application built with Akka 2 Futures. I don't need Actors currently but I'm not reluctant to use them.

Several computations enclosed in futures must invoke a random generator, very often. I'm afraid that if I used a classic concurrent RNG, it will become a choking point and I will lose scalability.

What is the most fast/simple way of having a Random generator per thread in the `ExecutionContext` ?

Is there a way to initialize them all with a different seed (but known in advance) such a to repeat experiment ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use akka.jsr166y.ThreadLocalRandom

Answer (score 4):

If using [`ThreadLocalRandom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) isn't an option, you can pretty easily write your own using [`ThreadLocal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) and Scala's [`Random`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.Random). Although providing "additional commonly used bounded random generation methods" is an exercise left to the interested developer.

```
object ThreadLocalRandom {
  private val localRandom = new ThreadLocal[util.Random] {
    override protected def initialValue() = new util.Random
  }

  def current = localRandom.get
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the Scala random generator; it's just a wrapper around Javas which you've probably noticed is synchronized.

Java 7 have a ThreadLocalRandom that is made for your use. If you can't use java 7 use another randomizer; for example the non-synchronized mersenna twister implementation from here: http://www.cs.gmu.edu/~sean/research/. Use this implementation through a ThreadLocal object so that each thread has one thats only initialized once. To seed the instances simply use a shared normal synchronized Random.